# Can't insert ContentControl over the table if it has different borders in rows

Tags: office-js

If table which i process have different borders, it is impossible to insert content control over it. Trouble only in word online. In desktop it works.
Code example:

```
    Word.run(async (context) => {
        let tables: Word.TableCollection = context.document.body.tables;
        tables.load();
        await context.sync();
        let rng = tables.items[0].getRange();
        rng.insertContentControl();
        return context.sync();
    }).catch((error) => {
        this.errorEmitter.emit(error);
    });
```

How to fix it?
Table example:
[differentBorders.docx](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/files/1159044/differentBorders.docx)

Comment: Hello Andrew, I think I need more detail from you on how to repro this issue. I can repro it with your attachment, however when I create a table manually and change the border in any row (this btw can only be done in the Win32 client, not on Online) I can successfully wrap the table with a content control.

Comment: Hello Juan, to reproduce this bug just change outer border with double click on cell . There is the file with examples: [borders.docx](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/files/1164847/borders.docx)

Comment: I don't see an outer border on your sample. are you merging cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew, thanks for pointing out this issue.

I think the root cause is that there is merged cells in the table and the failure of insertContentControl is not related to the borders.

We have already supported this issue in our local environment and will notify you when it is deployed to the production.

Comment: I'm excited to tell you that the extension feature has deployed to the production. You can have a try and let me know if there is some another problems.